# Pass Variable to Django Admin Form

Tags: python, html, django

I have an add form for CalibrationCertificates in my django admin site. If I link to it from a non-admin template, Instrument_Detail.html, is it possible to pass context information as a default value to the add form.

That is, the only choice in the add form is which Instrument the certificate is for. As the link is already associated with an instrument, is there a way to pass that value, such that the add certificate form will default to the instrument the user came from?

My ModelAdmin is as follows:

```
class CertificateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ('issued_by', 'expires',)
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.issued_by = request.user
        obj.expires= datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=obj.instrument.kind.duration)
        obj.save()
```

Comment: Could you please show your "add form for CalibrationCertificates" and your models?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly but I think this is what you want:

```
def add_view(self, request, form_url='', extra_context=None):
    extra_context = extra_context or {}
    extra_context['my_extra_content'] = self.something
    return super(MyModelAdmin, self).add_view(request, form_url, 
        extra_context=extra_context)
```